# Run EXCEL formula in VBA function

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a custom function in VBA which I call from cell and I have a formula like this

```
"=SUM(SUMIFS(CURR_COUNT;MDL;""MODEL"";CURR_MDLCD;{CODES};RG;""REGIONID""))/SUM(SUMIFS(CURR_COUNT;MDL;""MODEL"";RG;""REGIONID"";CURR_MDLCD;""<>     ""))"
```

My custom function take some cells values and insert them to formula which is just string. After that I need to calculate formula and return result to cell from which I call the function?
Can I calculate this formula in the function and return result to a cell?

Comment: `Application.WorksheetFunction`

Comment: @mojo Why not record it in the macro recorder?

Comment: I need to know is there any possibility to evaluate this kind of formula in function and return result?

Comment: Your answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41754122/4926357

Comment: Application.WorksheetFunction I think will solve my problem but when i try to pass array criteria it returns 0 but should return  >0 
`WorksheetFunction.Sum(WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(COUNT, MDL, Model, MDLCD, codes, RG, RegionId))`  codes = {123;25;37}, but if I set one code like 123 for example it calculates fine. What I did wrong?

Answer (score 9):

Assuming your formula string would work if it was actually put into a cell, then it should work if you use `Application.Evaluate` - but you don't include the equals sign.

e.g. To calculate

```
=SUM(A1:B1)
```

in VBA you would use

```
Application.Evaluate("SUM(A1:B1)")
```

Comment: Worked great.  Thank you.  version:  Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2202 Build 16.0.14931.20764) 64-bit